# Azure bot framework Composer publish with own json data files

Tags: botframework

I am using json files to store data that is loaded by an LG function. I have the json files within a custom directory under the dialog folder e.g.

```
mybot/
  dialogs/
    mydialog/
      knowledge-base
      language-generation
      language-understanding
      myfolder/
        myfile1.json
        myfile2.json
```

The path I use is relative to the dialog folder e.g.

```
# MyTemplate(name)
- ${json(fromFile(concat("../../myfolder/",name)))}
```

Works when testing locally, fails when deployed to Azure webapp

```
mydialog.en-us.lg:Could not find a part of the path ‘D:\home\site\wwwroot\ComposerDialogs\dialogs\mydialog\myfolder\myfile1.json'
```

Anyone know what the correct path name should be?

I've tried several different locations for "myfolder" - none work.

I suspect the question should be "How do I tell Composer to include this folder when it builds and deploys the bot?".

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags - as far as I see, this question is in no way related to [tag:composer-php]. If I am wrong, please add all relevant configuration to your question, this should include a `composer.json` and a better description about the problem

Comment: is your issue resolved?